# Error encountered during compile time - IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

There were no errors in the entire code. But on running the application, I get this error. The app is a social network app. I'm not yet done with it. I just wanted to test what I had done so far.

I'm using firebase as the backend. I've done all I know I should do. Thanks in advance for anyone to point out where the problem might be.

```
09-17 15:15:02.161 3113-3113/com.karpos.uiapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-17 15:15:02.182 3113-3119/com.karpos.uiapp E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
09-17 15:15:02.182 3113-3119/com.karpos.uiapp I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-17 15:15:02.259 3113-3113/com.karpos.uiapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.karpos.uiapp-1/lib/x86
09-17 15:15:15.057 3113-3113/com.karpos.uiapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.karpos.uiapp-1/lib/x86
09-17 15:15:15.163 3113-3113/com.karpos.uiapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
09-17 15:15:15.164 3113-3113/com.karpos.uiapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.karpos.uiapp, PID: 3113
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth implements non-interface class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaja (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth' appears in /data/data/com.karpos.uiapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-auth-9.0.2_d242e5a275ef165dea6bef1054c16b85330841ce-classes.dex)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
        at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-17 15:15:22.749 3113-3113/com.karpos.uiapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3113 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle and say something about what you recently changed in it?

Comment: Alright... I'll send it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all the latest firebase & google play libraries with same version.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

Comment: I'll try that out

Answer (score 0):

Had this myself just now...
It basically says that a file was changed while it shouldn't have been.
This usually occurs when your packagemanager is trying to be too smart.
Clear your caches, throw away build folders and build everyting from scratch.

For Android Studio that means:

- delete all build folders from all your modules
- gradle sync
- clean
- rebuild